# Transpose multiple rows into Single Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range `B2:Y194` of which I need to transpose from a row into a single column in cell `A196`, How would I go about doing this please?

I have tried this formula from another site but not quite sure how to tailor it to work on my range

```
=OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($2:2)/3,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($2:2)-1,3))
```

Comment: Change the `3`s to the number of columns in your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example as like you asked, please change the references as per your data requirement.

**Formula Used in A1:**  `=INDEX($C$2:$AA$671,1+INT((ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)/COLUMNS($C$2:$AA$671)),1+MOD(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1,COLUMNS($C$2:$AA$671)))`

> If this one not suits for your requirement, please let me know along with screenshot of
>   your data by modifying your question again.

[image]